# Bytearray to non-text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, http, corruption, file-access

I'm currently making a file-transfer server that gets chunks of 1024 bytes from files through DatagramPacket (this is a requirement for the assignment), and then assembles the file in a byte array, before sending it through HTTP. The system works great for any text file format, even really large .c/.txt/.sql files, so I know I'm getting the correct bytes through. However, when I try with anything else, like a .zip or a .png, when I open it on the other side, it comes out corrupted. This happens in really small images/zips as well. Any ideas why this happens?

Code from the class that creates the chunks:

```java
File f = new File(campos[2]);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

inputStream.skipNBytes(chunk);
if (f.length() > chunk + 1024)
    quantos = 1024;
else quantos = (int) f.length() - chunk;

byte[] dados = new byte[quantos];
inputStream.read(dados, 0, quantos);
inputStream.close();
pacote = new DatagramPacket(dados, quantos, address, porta);
socket.send(pacote);
```

Code from the server that gets all the chunks into a byte array:

```java
    while (tamanho > 0) {
        serv = procuraServidor();
        buf = ("Chunk " + chunk + " " + parametros[1].substring(1) + " ").getBytes();
        pacote = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, serv.getKey(), serv.getValue());
        dataSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        //pede os dados desse chunk
        dataSocket.send(pacote);
        buf = new byte[1500];
        pacote = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        dataSocket.receive(pacote);
        try {
            lock.lock();
            servidores.add(serv);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

        if (tamanho > chunkSize)
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, ficheiro, chunk*chunkSize, chunkSize);
        else System.arraycopy(buf, 0, ficheiro, chunk*chunkSize, tamanho);
        // iniciar thread para tomar conta do pedido
        tamanho-= chunkSize;
        chunkSet.add(chunk);
        chunk++;
    }

    out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
    out.write(("content type: " + Files.probeContentType(new File (parametros[1].substring(1)).toPath())).getBytes());
    out.write(ficheiro);
    out.flush();
}
```

I really have no clue why this is happening, and specifically in non text files.

Comment: Try to isolate your code into a stand-alone client and server program. You should take away all parts than are not part of your problem (for example, I see you are using locks). Lastly, please use English names in your code .

Comment: Thank you! I isolated it, and the issue remains. This is the code: ```File file = new File("code5.zip");
                byte[] test = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file);
                inp.read(test, 0, (int)file.length());
                
                
                out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
                out.write(("content type: " + Files.probeContentType(new File ("code5.zip").toPath())).getBytes());
                out.write(test);
                out.flush();       ```

Comment: I tested using just FileOutputStream instead of sending through HTTP, and the created file is flawless. So the problem has to be the HTTP transfer...

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't send CRLF after content-type, nor a content-length, and furthermore no CRLF to separate the content from the header fields.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't send CRLF after content-type, nor a content-length, and furthermore no CRLF to separate the content from the header fields.